# Trouble proving the floor function is onto with the domain being all real numbers

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing, real-numbers

I need to prove that for the mapping $f : \mathbb{R} \mapsto \mathbb{Z} $ given by $ f(x) = \lfloor x \rfloor$, $f$ is onto. I know how I would do it if both the domain and codomain were both $\mathbb{Z}$ but not if the domain is $\mathbb{R}$. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: HINT: What is $\lfloor n\rfloor$ when $n\in\Bbb Z$?

Comment: How would the proof look like for the domain being the integers? Does augmenting the domain to the reals change anything with your argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if $f : A \to B$ is onto and $A \subset C$ and $g: C \to B$ agrees with $f$ on $A$ then the image of $g$ must contain the image of $f.$

So if $f$ is onto so is $g.$

In this case $f$ is the identity map on the integers.